# Tomcat 8 - Invalid direct reference to form login page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, authentication, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to set up login functionality for a webapp by using j_security_control, but recently when I'm logging in I've been getting the error from the title.  Here is the relevant login jsp:

```
<div class="loginContainer">
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/j_security_check">
            <c:if test="${not empty param.Retry}">
                <div class="errorText">
                    <p>Login failed.  Please try again.</p>
                </div>
            </c:if>
            <div class="username">
                <label class="loginText" for="inputUser">User</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username" name="j_username" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label class="loginText" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="j_password">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn loginButton" id="loginButton">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

It's being called from a header as such:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">
        <a id="logout" href="${base}/jsp/login/logout.jsp"
           class="fse-hid-small navbartext"
           data-ng-class="{'selected': idSelected === 'logout'}"
           title="Goodbye!">LOGOUT</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a id="login" href="${base}/jsp/login/login.jsp"
           class="fse-hid-small navbartext"
           data-ng-class="{'selected': idSelected === 'login'}"
           title="Login Here!">LOGIN</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And defined in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>InternalUserRole</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsp/internal/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>InternalUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/jsp/login/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/jsp/login/login.jsp?Retry=True</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

This was working some time ago, unfortunately, I don't know when it broke.  Is there anyway for me to make this work?

Comment: I've tried clearing my cache and encoding the URL but I have the same issue.

Comment: I tried making a secure redirect and that gives me a Localhost refused to connect error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as no one else had a solution, I managed a hacky solution to get past this poor tomcat security issue.

1. Create a simple servlet that redirects to the root page.
2. Create a web-resource-collection entry that makes that servlet page secure and requires a role.
3. Make your link to the login page point to the servlet you created.

When you click that link, you'll be redirected to the login page you wanted to go to.  Login and you'll be redirected to the root index page.  A simple way to get around an incredibly annoying security error that isn't even helpful.